# How to Mock ClaimsPrincipal in unit test .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing

I am doing unit test on my controller method to information from ClaimsPrincipal object, but `Current.FindFirst()` returns nothing, can anyone help this? Thanks. (written in VB and C# is acceptable too):

```
  Public Class TestController
    Public Function GetEmail() As String
         Return ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value
    End Function
  End Class

<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test()
  //Arrange
    Dim fackClaimPrinciple = New Mock(Of ClaimsPrincipal)()
    Dim claims = New List(Of Claim)() From {New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user@hotmail.com")}
    fackClaimPrinciple.Setup(Function(e) e.Claims).Returns(claims)
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fackClaimPrinciple.[Object]

  // Act
  Dim result = TestController.GetEmail()

  '... ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value Returns nothing??

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocking is not working on ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst(), so it's fixed by using claim based function:

```
Public Class TestIdentity
    Inherits ClaimsIdentity
    Public Sub New(ParamArray claims As Claim())
        MyBase.New(claims)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestPrincipal
    Inherits ClaimsPrincipal
    Public Sub New(ParamArray claims As Claim())
        MyBase.New(New TestIdentity(claims))
    End Sub
End Class

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = New TestPrincipal(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user@hotmail.com"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can assign claims principle to current thread principle,

```
        // Make fack claims principle instance
        var fackClaimPrinciple = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();

        // Setup fack data
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>() {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user@hotmail.com")
        }.AsEnumerable();
        fackClaimPrinciple.Setup(e => e.Claims).Returns(claims);

        // Assign to current thread principle
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fackClaimPrinciple.Object;            

        // Act
        ViewResult result = homeController.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

Comment: @programthreasures thanks. I followed your code and the ClaimsPrincipal object is empty when calling controller GetEmail() method.

Comment: ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims(0).value returns correct value, but ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value got exception error.